# Finding C memory leak with valgrind freezes program

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, freeze, gdbserver

I'm using valgrind for the first time and I'm trying to use it to find a memory leak in my program (https://github.com/ardera/flutter-pi). The application is an embedded GUI application and communicates with some kernel devices directly. The architecture I execute it on is linux on ARMv7, hardfp ABI.

However, after I use valgrind to start my program, the process hangs completely, consuming 100% CPU on a single CPU core. The memory usage stays constant while it hangs. (The memory usage is well below 100% btw)

I can't use Ctrl+C to terminate it, sending *SIGTERM* via htop doesn't work, the vgdb commands I tried (like `vgdb v.info scheduler` or just `vgdb v.info`) don't work because the valgrind gdbserver doesn't send a reply to the pipe. If I use `--vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=1` and connect to the valgrind gdbserver via `gdb`, I can't even Ctrl+C there. I have to kill it using SIGKILL too.

Normally, there should be some logging in stdout and after 5 seconds, a GUI visible on my screen. If I use valgrind, after waiting for 15 minutes, there's no logging from my program at all in stdout and also no GUI.

Valgrind does output something though, mainly related to access to uninitialised memory. (Use of uninitialised value, conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value, etc) The full output is [here](https://pastebin.com/LcRuPuwL).

Does anyone know what causes this? Is this a bug in valgrind, or my code? Does anyone know alternative ways for finding memory leaks? If it's a bug in my code, how should I go about finding it?

Comment: warning *valgrind* interprets the binary, so the execution time is longer than the original. Out of that you have UB so by definition the execution can be the not the same as out of valgrind. So first remove all the UB to not have any messages from *valgrind* and have a 'normal' execution before to search for memory leaks

Comment: There are known issues using Valgrind, i.e. when using certain Valgrind in-line calls.  [This site](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html) list a few of them.  Search for words like crash.

Comment: Note that a conditional jump that depends on an uninitialized value may easily manifest itself as a "freeze", e.g. if it happens to control the exit condition of a loop. Valgrind may cause your unintialized value to be different from the value it would have in your usual environment.

Comment: I just debugged them, and all the undefined behaviour was ocurring at load-time, when ld-linux.so is loading my binary. (I backtraced the callstack at each error and _start was the common denominator.)

Comment: 9 year old Valgrind 3.7.0, seriously? Try with Valrind 3.16.1. That might fix your problems with dwarf debuginfo and ld.so.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that. 3.7.0 is the latest version available in the default raspbian package repo. Installed 3.16.1 now via snap and it works (it seems). Thanks!